# Помогите разобраться с регуляркой (парсить пользовательские теги)

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, php5

Хочу понять, как можно преобразовать пользовательские теги в HTML-теги. Суть такая. На сайте подключён bootstrap и там есть такая штука, как "значки" (badge). Используются они вот так:

```
<span class="badge badge-primary">N60+;J41+</span>
```

Появляется такая стилизация:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В целом мне нужно сделать регулярку, которая, к примеру, парсила строку:

```
{badge-secondary}N60+;J41+{/badge}
```

и переводила ее в вид:

```
<span class="badge badge-secondary">N60+;J41+</span>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, с этим...

Comment: ваши попытки, какие трудности? ваш вариант вместе  тестовыми данными можно выложить на https://regex101.com/

Comment: Получилось разобраться :)

Comment: Очень хорошо !!